# there is error when hit api Could not write JSON: Object is null

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

when I hit save to database, there is field is null like updated at and updated by. when I try to return it to controller there is error (Could not write JSON: Object is null)

Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: Object is null

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saving",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> save(
        @RequestHeader(value = "apps") String apps,
        @RequestHeader(value = "module") String module,
        @Valid @RequestBody CreateTemplate requestData) throws IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException, ApiResponseThrow 
    {
        
        log.info("START saveTemplateQontak function");
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        
        String jwt = AuthTokenFilter.parseJwt(request);
        String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

        LogFormat logFormat = new LogFormat();
        logFormat.setAction("saving");
        logFormat.setApps(apps);
        logFormat.setModule(module);
        logFormat.setUser(username);
        log.info("DATA BEFORE == {}", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestData));
        log.info("log-format == {}", logFormat);
        
        // JSONObject token = qontakService.getTokenQontak();
        // JSONObject res = qontakService.saveTemplateToQontak(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestData), token.get("access_token").toString());
        // requestData.getAttributes().get(0).getComponents().get(0).getType()
        JSONObject res = templateService.saveHeaderTemplate(requestData, logFormat);
        log.info("END templateService.save() CREATE");

        result.put("httpCode", HttpStatus.OK);
        result.put("status", "00");
        result.put("message", "Success Saving");
        result.put("details",res);

        log.info("END save function");

        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

error result is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Object is null (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["details"]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["template"]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["createTemplate"]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["attributes"]->net.sf.json.JSONArray[0]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["components"]->net.sf.json.JSONArray[1]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["example"]->net.sf.json.JSONNull["empty"])

Thank you.

Comment: What is `res` is this line `result.put("details",res);`? This variable doesn't appear anywhere else in the code you've shared.

Comment: As a sidenote, it would be cleaner to create a class representing your custom API-response rather than constructing the response manually via Map.